# Is there a keyboard shortcut to toggle Tree view / Places View?

Tags: nautilus, places

I find both the *Tree view* and the *Places view* useful. Changing from one view to the other is not fast because one have to go into the appearance menu. It's even slower with Oneiric because this menu can now be far away.
(Before Unity, I always had the tree view on and I used my bookmarks directly from the Places menu. That was fine)

Is there a **keyboard shortcut** to **toggle** from one view to the other? Or is it possible to create one oneself?

Thanks a lot the help !

Comment: No, not that I know of. I just know you can use F9 to toggle hide/show sidebar.

Comment: Are you still seeking an answer to this question?

Comment: Yes I am. Meanwhile, I use Dolphin as replacement. But I would prefer to stick with Nautilus.

Comment: Unfortunately **tree view** was removed from Nautilus, from version 3.10 at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method specific to Compiz / Ubuntu-3D:**

If you are using Ubuntu-3D, then you can use bind keyboard keys to terminal commands using CompizConfig Settings Manager.

1. **Warning**: CCSM is in universe and not shipped by default for a reason, it can be flaky, so be careful in there, [it can break things](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it), if you find yourself with a broken window manager, see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration) to reset your configuration.
2. Install the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) 
   (CCSM) by clicking on the link.

Click on "Commands".

[image]

The terminal commands to switch between "tree" and "places" are as follows:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state side-pane-view "tree"
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state side-pane-view "places"
```

Copy them to appropriate columns and assign keys to these commands to your wish. Here, I have chosen Ctrl + 5 and Ctrl + 6. Once you have done it properly, you can input your chosen keyboard shortcuts and see Nautilus change its view at your fingertips.

[image: Commands]

[image: Keybindings]

**Alternate method (Not limiting to Compiz / Unity - 3D):**

Search for "Keyboard" settings. Open "Shortcuts" tab. Move to "Custom Shortcuts" and click the + button. Give the shortcut appropriate name and assign keyboard shortcuts as you wish.

You should use the following commands for switching between "tree" and "places":

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state side-pane-view "tree"
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.window-state side-pane-view "places"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for the great answer!
Setting the keyboard shortcuts through the Keyboard Settings didn't work for me. I tried assigning `Ctrl+5` and `Ctrl+6` to `side-pane-view "tree"` and `side-pane-view "places"`, respectively.

Comment: Sorry, bummer, part of the comment was lost.
The compiz solution worked great though. Awesome.
Thanks a again.

Comment: @zinzolin Sorry, I didn't complete the answer properly. For the keyboard shortcut to work, you should be using the entire command. I have edited the answer. So, it should be quite clear now.

Answer (score 4):

[This Nautilus extension](https://github.com/vitaut/captain-nemo) allows you to edit keyboard shortcuts (accelerators).

After installing the extensions go to `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts...` in the main menu and search for actions starting from `Sidebar` in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` dialog. Click the Key cell corresponding to the action you need such as `Sidebar Tree` and enter a shortcut:

[image]

The keyboard shortcuts that you enter will even show up in the main menu:

[image]

Comment: I wish this were integrated into nautilus natively... (don't really want to use and trust a 3rd-party addon for such an elementary thing)

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the "list view" in Nautilus, that is easily accessed by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

As for the sidebar, there is no shortcut for changing this setting.

Comment: Hello Roland! No, I meant to have a keyboard shortcut to toggle pane view from folders to places. In Dolphin for example, the following keyboard shortcuts are available: F9 displays the places and F7 the folders (there are even more keyboard shortcuts: F11 displays the informations, F12 the search, and F4 the Terminal)